# classList.toggle() not working after cloning in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div id="template">

    <label><h1>Enter your title</h1></label>
    <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Enter your title">
    <label><p>Enter your text</p></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="textbox1[]" placeholder="Enter your text"></textarea>

</div>
```

I clone this div and append it using JavaScript. On click on a button, the div is supposed to open by toggling the .open class.

Relevant JavaScript:

```
function addClonedDiv() {

    var div = document.getElementById('template');
    window.clonedDiv = div.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('otherDiv').appendChild(clonedDiv);
    clonedDiv.firstChild.className = "newDiv";
}

function addIframe() {

    clonedDiv.firstChild.classList.toggle("open");

}
```

(There's two buttons, one clones the div and the other one shows it, it's hidden by default, otherDiv is the div I want to append the new div to. I add the class="newDiv" to it because I will need it later for other purposes which are not relevant to this question, however, I wanted to include it as I don't know if that may be the problem).
The .open class in CSS:

```
.open {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, when I click on the button that is supposed to show the div, I get this error message in the console: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined.
I'm not sure why the new div would be undefined and how to fix that.

I read through other questions on here that said that I have to deep clone the div, which I tried applying (as you can see), but I still received the same error message. I know cloning doesn't clone event-handlers, but I'm pretty sure, that that is not the problem in my case.

I did read through plenty of other questions and did my research, however, I could not fix the problem. I definitely want to solve this problem in JavaScript and not jQuery.

Comment: "div is supposed to open"; can u elaborate on that??

Comment: `.toggle()` is jQuery method, before using this, you should include jQuery library..

Comment: by default it's hidden (I didn't show that code), when you click on the button it becomes visible. I use it like an iframe of sorts, like it takes up the whole screen and when clicking on x it closes again, if that makes sense

Comment: @SuperUser the jquery library is actually included, maybe I have to move it to the top of the document (I just tried it and it still gives me the same error message)

Comment: @SuperUser `classList.toggle` has nothing to do with jQuery `.toggle()`, it's a native method.

Comment: @A.S.J Can you make a minimum reproducible Fiddle or Codepen?

Comment: @TigranPetrossian https://jsfiddle.net/thuvh25s/ hope that helps

Comment: You have class 'otherDiv', not id, just in case...

Comment: @sinisake ah I made that mistake when writing the code for the jsfiddle, it's not in my actual code, but thanks for making me aware of this, I fixed it https://jsfiddle.net/thuvh25s/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems here (and even more in your fiddle, but since you seem to have gotten until the error message you quoted, I'll fix the ones of the fiddle for free).

**Error repro:**

```js
function addClonedDiv() {
  var div = document.getElementById('template');
  window.clonedDiv = div.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('otherDiv').appendChild(clonedDiv);
  clonedDiv.firstChild.className = "newDiv";
};
// open is reserved
function open_() {
  console.log(clonedDiv);
  clonedDiv.firstChild.classList.toggle("open");
};
```

```css
#template {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.newDiv.open {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="otherDiv">
  <button onclick="addClonedDiv()">
    Add Item
    </button>
  <button onclick="open_()">
    Open
    </button>
</div>
<div id="template">

  <label><h1>Enter your title</h1></label>
  <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Enter your title">
  <label><p>Enter your text</p></label>
  <textarea type="text" name="textbox1[]" placeholder="Enter your text"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

So let's first fix the error message:

[`clonedDiv.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) is a Node, and even a textNode, representing a new line character. So you can set a property to it, but it doesn't inherit from Element nor from HTMLElement prototypes and thus doesn't have a `classList` property.

What you want is [`clonedDiv.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) (in `addCloneDiv` too).

Then, [`Node.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) will copy all the attributes of an Element, when called on an Element. So your `clonedDiv` will also have the `id="template"` attribute. This means that your `.newDiv.open` rule will have less importance than the `#template` one.

```js
function addClonedDiv() {
  var div = document.getElementById('template');
  window.clonedDiv = div.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('otherDiv').appendChild(clonedDiv);
  clonedDiv.firstElementChild.className = "newDiv"; // grab the first Element
  clonedDiv.removeAttribute('id'); // ids must be unique per document
};

function open_() {

  clonedDiv.firstElementChild.classList.toggle("open");

};
```

```css
#template,
.newDiv {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.newDiv.open {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="otherDiv">
  <button onclick="addClonedDiv()">
    Add Item
    </button>
  <button onclick="open_()">
    Open
    </button>
</div>
<div id="template">

  <label><h1>Enter your title</h1></label>
  <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Enter your title">
  <label><p>Enter your text</p></label>
  <textarea type="text" name="textbox1[]" placeholder="Enter your text"></textarea>

</div>
```

Now I'm not sure this is really what you wanted to occur, but I'll let you find yourself.

Comment: oh wow this actually fixed it perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```js
var clonedDiv;
function clone(){
    clonedDiv = document.getElementById('template').cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('otherDiv').appendChild(clonedDiv);
    clonedDiv.className = "newDiv";
}
function show(){
(!clonedDiv.classList.contains("open")) ? clonedDiv.classList.add("open"):clonedDiv.classList.remove("open");
}
```

```css
.newDiv{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.open {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="template">

    <label><h1>Enter your title</h1></label>
    <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Enter your title">
    <label><p>Enter your text</p></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="textbox1[]" placeholder="Enter your text"></textarea>
    <button onclick="clone()">clone</button>
    <button onclick="show()">show</button>
</div>
<div id="otherDiv">

</div>
```

instead of toggle

Comment: now it says "Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined". I don't understand why my clone is undefined or how I could define it

Comment: clonedDiv is a local variable , you have to make it global

Comment: don't you make it global using "window.", also, I tried putting the whole cloning operation in one function, so it clones the div when the "add Item" button is clicked AND display it but it still doesn't work

Comment: hm it's not throwing an error message, but it's still not displaying it. The button, which triggers the onclick event is located within a template, which I generate. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Nevermind, an alert is working so if it was because of the template that shouldn't work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159375/discussion-between-anand-paul-and-a-s-j).